# What is the correct approach to update only specific fields in Spring Boot using Spring Data JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository, crud

[image: this is my update method]
[image: my update request class]
[image: and my modelmapper forRequest]
[image: and controller]

I just want to update just some field.

For example; just name or password or gmail but when ı try to add just one field, other datas is being recorded null. How can ı solve this problem? Should ı try to add @Query for my repository ?

Comment: Please don't post source code as image but formatted text only.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a **User** model and a corresponding repository name **UserRepository**:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Now create an instance of this UserRepository like:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;
```

Then update your User data:

```
var user = userRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow();
user.setName(name); // password or email
userRepo.save(user);
```

**Note**: CrudRepository interface has  **Optional findById(ID id)** method definition.
Since Optional reference, If no user found it throws an exception, use orElseThrow().

Comment: Explanation given by updated previous code. Check pls.